# OAuth2 for Office365 REST API for Java Application

Tags: java, azure, office365, outlook-restapi

I have created a simple application in Java which Connects to my Office 365 Account and retrieve the unread messages. I am performing some text matching and pattern matching to generate some reports which I receive via Email.

I am using the below url with basic Authentication to do so.

https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/me/messages?$filter=IsRead%20eq%20false

However, I have read a couple of articles and most of them have suggested that Basic Authentication will not be supported and suggested to use OAUTH2.0.

I am not sure how to use OAUTH2.0. A couple of articles mention about registering the Application with AAD for which i need to have access to Azure Management Portal which i do not have. Please can any one guide me how this can be done.

PS: I am using my Corporate Domain Account to access Office

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that Basic will not continue to be supported. You do not need the Azure management portal to register an application, you can use the App Dev portal (apps.dev.microsoft.com) to get a client ID and secret.

Here's a walkthrough for creating a Java web app from scratch: https://dev.outlook.com/restapi/tutorial/java. It shows how to register the app and do the authentication.

Comment: Thanks Jason.. this will certainly help...I am not working on a Web App though.. What i have is a simple Standalone Java Application which works with HTTPClient. If you have anything in that area it will help.

Comment: Found a way... I have authorized app for offline access (ie. scope=offline_access....) and able to retrieve Refresh Token with every access token request which i am saving into a file safely. when the first token expires. I am simply reusing the refresh token to grab a new one without login. Is this approach correct? I don't think Refresh Token have expiry..Please Clarify

Comment: Yes, you are on the right track. From a native app you could also pop up a browser for the initial sign-in and receive auth code part. Refresh tokens expire after 14 days, but once you use them you get a new one that is good for another 14 days.

Comment: I have a requirement to pull the exchange logs from Office365, Simple Standalone Java Application which works with HTTPClient. If you have anything in that area it will help.

Comment: @yalamandalavenkateswarlu: were you able to develop something for your requirement?

Comment: @Nishant: How did you achieve that? Could you please help.